# Configuring Eclipse Code Analysis

Tags: eclipse, code-analysis

I have been using Eclipse Code Analysis for C++ for a little while. I have now tried applying it to an existing project and am having some problems getting rid of the noise.

Is there a way of excluding files from the analysis? I have found ways of turning off files for individual rules, but am looking for a global control.

Also, I want to be able to set up system headers to be inspected as required and as included so that the undefined variable count is cut down. Is this possible?

The code compiles and runs fine at the moment so this tool is currently too sensitive.

I have alreadyfound some potential bugs using this tool and would like to tune it better. I am using Eclipse Indigo with Codan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the feature you want is marked as [future work](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/designs/StaticAnalysis#Future_work). But, you can always try to create your checker, like it is explained [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/designs/StaticAnalysis#For_Developers).